# arranging random numbers html version

Tags: javascript, html

i need to display 5 random numbers that i arranged from lowest to highest.

here is my code.

i haven't put the algo for the lowest and highest.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p></p>
       <script type="text/javascript">
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
 var randNum = 0;
 var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
 document.write(randNum + "\n");
}
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Can't find a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display the unique numbers randomly. With the current code you're faced with repeating random numbers. An array with fixed numbers would be better here. So you can delete the numbers already selected:

```js
numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (var i = 0, len = numberArray.length; i < len; i++) {
  var randNum = 0;
  randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberArray.length);
  document.body.innerHTML += numberArray.splice(randNum, 1);
}
```

I'm using `splice` to delete the selected index element from the array. `Splice` returns the element so we can print it on the page. Splice takes to arguments: starting index and length.

`randNum` is based on each length of the current array, while the loop itself is based on the original length of the array.

Also avoid using `document.write` unless you know exactly what you're doing. Use DOM manipulation instead.

Of course you can also let JavaScript create the array for you if you have a lot of numbers:

```
var numberArray = []; //create empty array
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    numberArray.push(i); //push number to array
}
```